# Dealing with a situation where my colleague demands i repeat documentation in their format even if it means duplication

Tags: software-industry, communication, work-environment, colleagues

Dealing with a situation where my colleague demands i repeat documentation in their format even when i have it somewhere else already documented with the way i want it to be formatted.
This truly is duplication. Although the purpose of her doc is different slightly than mine, the information is the same - probably more in my docs. just that the colleague wants everything documented in 1 single place, and i have organized it based on functionality / category. 
it is so difficult to convince my colleague that what will be done will be waste of time and efforts. but the response i get is - if i dont do it, he will. how to convince the person that it doesnt matter who does it, it is an ask for too much time and efforts for duplicating work?!

Comment: `if i dont do it, he will` -> so let him? That way you've got a perfectly serviceable document in a format you like, and he gets one in a format he likes. Is there some other advantage to his format (even a political reason such as "the boss prefers it in that format" ?)

Comment: i believe my colleague believes that the boss will prefer in that way - atleast she seems to have made a good marketing pitch for it. and the most annoying thing is - the pitch is bought , looks like, by most of my team mates - and i am having to conform for no reason. so much other work pressure and this is being added to top it all. or is it in my mind, that i feel the need to conform? not sure...

Comment: If most of your team mates agree with your colleague, have you considered that he might actually be right?

Comment: @varini: Having read your other question(s), I think you really need to take a step back and swallow your pride.  If two paths are presented and the team selects one then the *Right* thing to do is to stop arguing and get on board with it.  It shouldn't be taken as a personal attack when your ideas aren't picked.  Instead you should let go of yours and spend some time understanding why everyone liked the other one.

Comment: @Chris - I have not fought back. i supported my colleague. As there is no time to fight or argue over these things. but i did try my best to make her understand. my team mates do not know what is needed to get the documnt. they do not know its available elsewhere and do not know if its repetition / duplicate work. i know if they did, they would support me. i somehow could not argue over it with her in front of the team

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that there are two competing, but *both worthy* goals here:

- Your desire to have things documented by category / functionality
- Your colleague's desire to have everything documented in one place.

The thing to remember here is that when your colleague is saying "we should do things this way", it doesn't imply "your work is worthless" - it's just saying that they believe that the goal of having everything in one place is more important than having things documented by category.

Take a step back here (it may help to stop thinking about things as "my work" and "their work" - remember that neither of you own any of this, your employer does) and try and look at the bigger picture - which of the competing goals is more important for the company in the long run? If you still believe that having things organised by category is more important, sit down with your colleague and  explain to them why that's more important than having everything in one place. If after discussing things with them, the two of you still can't come to an agreement, talk to your manager / team lead - one of the most important jobs of a leader is to resolve disputes within a team. If your manager disagrees with you, then it's almost certainly time to accept the decision with good grace (although potentially to work on a scheme to reduce the amount of duplicated work that that happens).

Answer (score 7):

There are many reasons that a particular format may be required for some data.

It may be a regulatory thing, it may be a consistency thing, it may be that your coworker is a jerk. I, personally, wouldn't be so quick to jump on that last reason though... typically people have a reason for what they do and why they do it. You find it silly to duplicate work but the question should be: Why does it need to be in that format for that worker? Why does it need to be in your format of choice for you?

The easiest solution would be to automate something that takes your report and dumps the data into their desired format. Sure it's a little bit of work but it's the least stressful way of handling the situation plus it shows flexibility and ambition on your behalf.

A more reasonable solution, perhaps, would be to start a dialog. What is it about this coworker's format that is important to them? How is it fundamentally different from the report you already generate? What resolution can you two come to as peers to solve the issue? It could be as simple as a different layout. Alternatively, if your coworker is willing to redo the data to fit their needs - let them do it!

It sounds, right now, like you, at least, have made this personal and that is never a healthy way to resolve issues like this. You should take a step back and really identify the issue here. Is it that you need different things? Is it that you are frustrated a peer isn't happy with a change you made? Is it something else?

Comment: the only difference is - that the colleague needs it all in 1 place. i personally feel demotivated looking at the doc he has made as it looks mammoth like and difficult to navigate and understand. the data is the same in mine and his. yes, i am frustrated :)

Comment: Why do you feel demotivated looking at a report that your colleague needs to use? If you coworked needs all the information in one place then that's on your colleague. You really need to step back from this because these are the kinds of slightly petty things that can hurt your career in unexpected way. I mean think about it, if your colleague wants to look at a fugly report - that's totally not your problem.

Comment: the report is going to be used by a lot of people. not sure if they r going to indeed read it - not my problem. but the issue is the team feels he is doing great work with the report as it looks good, and even if the whole thing is simply a copy-paste its making an impression in the team.

Comment: shouldnt somebody stealing my thunder a reason for concern? i dont know how to deal with this . please comment @Nahkki !!

Comment: Please don't use comments for chat; that's what chat rooms are for.

Answer (score 1):

And where is your boss is all this? Is the final decision his? Have you made a business case for why your way is better or are you just whining about it?

It appears as if your collegue has won the other team members over, so you will probably have to go with the format the team wants. You can't have everything your way at work and fighting something like this makes you appear childish and petty and that is bad for your career.

In your professional career you will lose professional disagreements at times, sometimes often and sometimes things that are genuinely critical. To win more, you need to learn about how office politics works and to play the game effectively. But even then, there are times when the decision does not go your way. You need to graciously accept decisions that you don't agree with and stop pushing the issue once the decision has been made.

You also need to consider the relative importance of choosing to fight for what you want before the decison has been made. I wouldn't waste my political capital on how to do documentation unless I was a technical writer.

Save your disagreements for things of far more importance. By graciously giving in when the issue is of little importance, you gain political capital and allies for when the issue is genuinely important. This is not a loss for you in the long run, it is a way to get people on your side later when it is something bigger than dovcumentation. The world works on compromise, learn to use it so that by giving some here, you get more later when it is more critical.